# What means the numbers besides my default policy chain rules?

Tags: iptables

I am investigating a potential security issue in one of my system. My firewall tables currently look as,

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [527:57388]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [189:35832]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9238 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
```

So, as per my understanding, the firewall rules imply that I can have incoming requests on my machine from ports **527** to **57388**.

I can create outgoing connections from my machine on the ports **189** to **35832**.

Is my above understanding correct?

If my above understanding is correct, I could try `http://servername` where http protocol uses port 80. How am able to do it if my rule has  `:INPUT ACCEPT [527:57388]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `iptables -v -L` instead of `iptables-save` you would be noticed that that's the amount of packets:bytes that has passed trough that specific chain. My own example:

```
➜  ~  sudo iptables-save  
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Oct 31 11:08:58 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [269:87691]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [234:37262]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 31 11:08:58 2014
➜  ~  sudo iptables -v -L 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 296 packets, 95092 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 252 packets, 39353 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

The number is a bit off, because I'm actively using the connection, but you can see how near are each number of each chain are in `X packets, Y bytes` to the one generated by iptables-save `[X:Y]`. That's what those numbers means.

Comment: thanks. So the only rule in my iptables currently is to accept connections on port 9238. Is that right?

Comment: @Ramesh that and any package that is not rejected by another rule.